# C# Proper solution needed for "can't specify constructor/static method in interface" problem

Tags: c#

Okay, I need some help here.

This is the same old **"can't use an interface to enforce constructors/static methods"** problem.

**WHAT IS THE PROPER OO DESIGN THEN??**

I have a set of data entities (Entity Framework stuff) for which I wrote partial class methods to convert to/from XML (XElement objects).

I have an instance method to "save" XML:

```
// Convert entity to XML
public XElement ToXml() {}
```

...and I have a constructor to "read" XML:

```
// Create entity from XML constructor.
public MyEntity(XElement) {}
```

Alternatively, I could use a static factory method to "read" XML:

```
public static MyEntity ParseXml(XElement) {}
```

**The dilemma:**

1. I could create an interface that mandates the "save" `ToXml()` method, but what good is that if it only addresses half the problem? An interface can't enforce either of the "load" methods.
2. I could rely on my own good intent to create these methods without any sort of contract.
3. I could create a static class filled with redundant methods like `XmlToEntity1()` and `XmlToEntity2()`, etc... (Now I've described a good 'generics' problem.) However, the specific conversion code (which is specific to each entity) would create separate methods or switch/case for each and seems to belong inside the entity classes, not in some other class, no?

**If an experienced C# coder can show a good design for this common problem I think I would learn a lot from it.**

Happy 4th of July!

## Possible Solution 1

A single `XmlSerializer` class with two static generic methods:

```
public static T Deserialize<T>(XElement xml) {}
public static XElement Serialize<T>(T entity) {}
```

- Pro: Only one class (no interface needed)
- Pro: Separates serialization responsibility from entity classes.
- Con: Would still require separate methods or switch/case blocks for each entity type supported.
- Con: ? Not extensible -- have to modify this class each time an entity changed or added/deleted.

## Possible lessons learned?

The "can't use interface for constructors and static methods" problem might be a symptom of:

1. Violating the SRP (Single Responsibility Principal).
2. Violating the SoC (Separation of Concern) principal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would be a good design to have the storage/retrieval separate from the entity anyway. In OO terms this can be referred to as the Single Responsibility Principle. Your entity exists for some purpose (probably related to your domain). The storage of that entity is a separate responsibility that could change independent of the domain. (e.g. you could retrive it from a database, a web service or the file system).

Static methods are not the only way to do this of course. You could create an interface at the save/retrive level and implement that interface for each of the entities. Then you could easily use those in a generic way without worrying a lot about the types.

Adding some example code:

```
interface EntityGateway<TEntity> {
    TEntity Load(String id);
    void Save(TEntity entity);
}
public class XEntityGateway implements EntityGateway<XEntity> {
    XEntity Load(String id) { ... implementation details } 
    void Save(XEntity entity) { ... implementation details } 
}

XEntityGateway gw = new XEntityGateway();
XEntity entity = gw.Load("SOMEID");
// modify entity
gw.Save(entity);
```

Comment: Okay, I'm familiar with SRP. So, you are suggesting a whole separate set of small classes (one-to-one) to provide a layer of separation? Sounds fair, even if it creates a whole slew of "mirror" classes. Though don't I end up with the very same problem enforcing a static factory method on those classes? I'm a little unclear about your non-static suggestion... how a non-static solution would look.

Comment: It might be a one-to-one between entity and mapper. There are a lot of common solutions to this captured in things like Patterns of Enterprise Application Architecture (PEAA). In a Table Data Gateway (for example) you could have an XEntityGateway. An instance of that would be created to save or load an XEntity. Each entity would follow the same pattern. When they are interface-driven instances instead of static, it will be much easier to test your system because you'll be able to mock out this data layer during unit testing.

Comment: I think I'm following you as saying create another data access layer (DAL) for XML persistence that communicates with the entities as a repository only (which I think is the proper way of doing EF)? Keep in mind this is just a personal application--I like doing things "right" and want to learn, but probably won't be mocking and testing. A simple, but correct architecture is what I'm looking for along with learning a good practice pattern.

Comment: Re-reading your comment several times over. I like it, but somewhat struggling to envision such a non-static XEntity interface that could be consumed by an XEntityGateway. Would *very much* appreciate if you could supply a couple lines of pseudo-C# with an edit to your answer!

Comment: The interface I was talking about would be implemented by the Gateway classes not the Entity classes. The Gateways could all implement the load(some id) and save(Entity) methods.

Answer (score 5):

What about using a simple instance method for loading from XML as well? Your interface would then be something like:

```
public interface XmlSerializableEntity
{
   XElement Serialize(); // or ToXml() if you prefer..
   void Deserialize(XElement e); // or Load() or something like that..
}
```

Or you could use a generic solution:

```
public interface Serializable<T>
{
   T Serialize();
   void Deserialize(T e);
}
```

The downside is that you have to initialize the entity object before you load it, which might mean you'll have an object in an invalid state. But I do believe this is a common pattern.

Comment: An instance method for loading requires that you have an instance already where none exists. Doesn't seem proper.

Comment: Yes, I agree, it's not perfect.

Comment: How about a single XmlEntitySerializer class with static generic methods? Upside: No interface/base-class needed (only 1 class with 2 methods). Downside: Both methods would still require a slew of private methods (again, 1-for-1) to support each entity type. Another upside: Seems to be good SRP? Yes?

Comment: The serializer you describe would appear to have one responsibility - XML serialization - but it will have dependencies on all entities, and probably need to change all the time - which is not good.